# Disabled OpenGL and when i reenabled it, I couldn't reactivate features

Tags: opengl

Through to a test on gaming performance I disabled  OpenGL and all of its features and lost me multi workspaces (I had 4) I reactivated it, rebooted my pc and still don't get all its features back. (still have 1 workspace) How can I change it back the way it was?

I saw when disabling it that I turn off a lot of features so i would like to know if it is possible to reactivate all of them...

I use Ubuntu 12.04 i386 and run the on Gnome Classic.

Comment: How did you disable OpenGL????????

Comment: i used Compiz Config Setting Manager-> General -> OpenGL theres a box you can tick or untick it...

Answer (score 0):

## Reset Compiz Configurations

Run this in Terminal:

> rm -r ~/.config/compiz-1; rm -r ~/.gconf/compiz-1; rm -r ~/.gconf/compizconfig-1; rm -r ~/.compiz-1

Then reboot your computer.